# What does the phrase 「まってちゃぶだい」 mean?

Tags: manga, phrases

Here is a sentence said by a kid to officers wanting them to do something.

**まってちゃぶだい**　まっておじさま　やるよ　やってみせるよっ。

I found that ちゃぶだい means 'tea table' but I don't know if it is related to the meaning of waiting someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a pun of 待ってちょうだい.

～てちょうだい is a friendly phrase which is used when you want to get someone to do something.

Answer (score 3):

> 死語辞典1-1  www.orange.ne.jp/~kibita/dwd/dwddic11.html
>    ちゃぶ台(名) テーブルのこと。座卓。 (関)許してちゃぶ台＝ちょうだい(頂戴).

Here (above) it says "Kansai slang" but i disagree.

I'm pretty sure the pun comes from the Kyuu-kana 旧かな  for    ちょうだい
--- which is ちゃうだい or     ちやうだい

Comment: そのサイト、凡例に「(関)」は載っていないようですが、他の例を見る限り、「関西弁」という意味ではなく「関連語」か「関連表現」のようなものを指しているようです。

Comment: Ok, thank you!   A similar expression is 「許してちょんまげ」